# How do I use my own reference types as the data type of a dataview column

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, datacolumn

I have a DataTable which contains columns, some of which have a data type which is the type of a class in my project, so the column would be added to the table thus:

```
DataColumn column = _dataTable.Columns.Add("myColumnName", typeof(MyClass));
```

The problem comes when I create a DataView from the DataTable and try to set a RowFilter:

```
_dataView.RowFilter = "[myColumnName] = \"xyz\"";
```

This throws an exception "Cannot perform '=' operation on MyClass and System.String".

MyClass implements IComparable as well as Equals(object obj), ToString() and all the equality and comparison operators, but this is obviously not enough. I even tried adding a conditional branch to CompareTo(object obj) to accept an obj that is a string, but to no avail, it never even hits CompareTo.

Presumably the expression parser in DataView is simply unable to work out how to compare a MyClass to a string.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

As requested by Cee McSharpFace, here is the relevant part of my class:

```
public class PartNumber : IXmlSerializable, IComparable<PartNumber>, IArithmetic, IEquatable<PartNumber>, IEquatable<string>, IComparable<string>
{
    public int CompareTo(PartNumber other)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (other is null)
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            DoActualComparison(other);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public int CompareTo(string other)
    {
        return ToString().CompareTo(other);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return !(obj is null) &&
               obj is PartNumber &&
               this == ((PartNumber)obj);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(PartNumber x, PartNumber y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y) == 0;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(PartNumber x, PartNumber y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
    public static bool operator >(PartNumber x, PartNumber y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y) > 0;
    }
    public static bool operator <(PartNumber x, PartNumber y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y) < 0;
    }
    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return ToString().Equals(other);
    }
    public bool Equals(PartNumber other)
    {
        return Equals((object)other);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(PartNumber lhs, string rhs)
    {
        return lhs.ToString() == rhs;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(PartNumber lhs, string rhs)
    {
        return lhs.ToString() != rhs;
    }
    public object Add(object x)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public object Subtract(object x)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public object Multiply(object x)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public object Divide(object x)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MakeObjectIntoString();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it `IEquatable` as well? Please show the custom type definition.

Comment: I've tried IEquatable, in fact I've tried every interface I can think of (see edited post). I suspect this is more down to a weakness in the expression evaluation that DataView implements, but I don't know how to get around it - hoping someone in the community knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a column of type `PartNumber` maps to the internal `StorageType.Object` in the datatable.

The binary operations evaluator does not support any of its operators on this storage type:

[Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Filter/BinaryNode.cs,233), this is where it throws the exception you've got. The list of supported types is listed in the switch statement a few dozen lines further up.

**Workaround 1:**

Add a second column where you store just the `PartNumber.ToString()` result, precomputed, to use in the query.

To make your code compile, and for demonstration purposes, I've added a private string field for the part number, which I return in its `ToString` override:

```
public struct PartNumber : IComparable<PartNumber>, IEquatable<PartNumber>, IEquatable<string>, IComparable<string>
{
    private readonly string actualPartnumber;

    public PartNumber(string samplePartnumber) => this.actualPartnumber = samplePartnumber;

    /* ... */

    public override string ToString() => actualPartnumber;
}
```

Usage:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var column = dataTable.Columns.Add("myColumnName", typeof(PartNumber));
var columnStr = dataTable.Columns.Add("myColumnNameStr", typeof(String));
var newRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow1["myColumnName"] = new PartNumber("abc");
newRow1["myColumnNameStr"] = newRow1["myColumnName"].ToString();
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow1);
var newRow2 = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow2["myColumnName"] = new PartNumber("xyz");
newRow2["myColumnNameStr"] = newRow2["myColumnName"].ToString();
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow2);

var dataView = new DataView(dataTable)
{
    RowFilter = "[myColumnNameStr] = 'xyz'"
};

Console.WriteLine(dataView.Count);
```

--> this returns one row, as you would expect.

**Workaround 2**

The [Convert function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Filter/FunctionNode.cs,112) can deal with `StorageType.Object` and is able to convert a `PartNumber` instance to a string using its `ToString` properly. So this would also work:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("myColumnName", typeof(PartNumber));
var newRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow1["myColumnName"] = new PartNumber("abc");
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow1);
var newRow2 = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow2["myColumnName"] = new PartNumber("xyz");
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow2);

var dataView = new DataView(dataTable)
{
    RowFilter = "CONVERT([myColumnName], System.String) = 'xyz'"
};

Console.WriteLine(dataView.Count);
```

--> I tested it, and it also returns the correct (and only) match.

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you. i really should put more effort into tracking down the code on the Microsoft site when I have these problems. I've still got a problem converting to int and double - I get a "does not implement IConvertible" error, but I can probably work that out - but it'll be Monday now.